# Method error "not all control paths return a value" and Method not returning a value

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I'm getting the following errors with my code:

PoliceOfficer.cpp(39): warning C4715: 'PoliceOfficer::patrol': not all control paths return a value

ParkingTicket.cpp(54): error C4716: 'GetCarInfo': must return a value

I've commented out most of the PoliceOfficer::patrol so it is easier to troubleshoot. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've included all my files just in case something helps

```
        Car.h


    #pragma once
    #ifndef CAR_H
    #define CAR_H
    #include <string>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    // Car class contains the information about a car
    
    class Car
    {
    private:
        string make, model, color, licenseNumber;
    
    public:
        // Default Constructor
        Car();
    
        // Accessors
        string getMake();
        string getModel();
        string getColor();
        string getLicense();
    
        // Mutators
        void setMake(string);
        void setModel(string);
        void setColor(string);
        void setLicense(string);
    
        // Overload << operator
        friend ostream& operator << (ostream& strm, const Car& obj);
    
    };
    
    
    
    #endif // CAR_H
```

```
        Car.cpp


    #include "Car.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    
    // Default Constructor
    Car::Car()
    {
        make = "None Set";
        model = "None Set";
        color = "None Set";
        licenseNumber = "None Set";
    }
    
    // Accessors
    string Car::getMake()
    {
        cout << "Make: " << make;
        return make;
    
    }
    string Car::getModel()
    {
        cout << "Model: " << model;
        return model;
    }
    string Car::getColor()
    {
        cout << "Color: " << color;
        return color;
    }
    string Car::getLicense()
    {
        cout << "License: " << licenseNumber;
        return licenseNumber;
    }
    
    // Mutators
    void Car::setMake(string ma)
    {
        make = ma;
    }
    void Car::setModel(string mo)
    {
        model = mo;
    }
    void Car::setColor(string c)
    {
        color = c;
    }
    void Car::setLicense(string l)
    {
        licenseNumber = l;
    }
    
    // Overload << operator
    // Author note: I'm not sure what I am supposed to be overloading
    // this function with. 
    ostream& operator << (ostream& strm, const Car& obj)
    {
        return  strm;
    }
```

```
        ParkedCar.h


    #pragma once
    #ifndef PARKEDCAR_H
    #define PARKEDCAR_H
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include "Car.h"
    
    using namespace std;
    
    // ParkedCar class simulates a parked car. Knows which type of car is parked and 
    // the number of minutes that the car has been parked
    
    class ParkedCar
    {
    private:
        // Private Members
    //  class Car;
        Car carObject;
        string make;
        string model;
        string color;
        string licenseNumber;
        int minutesParked;
    
    public:
        // Constructors
        ParkedCar();
        ParkedCar(string ma, string mo, string c, string l, int mp);
    
        // Copy Constructor
        ParkedCar(ParkedCar& obj);
    
        // Accessors
        int getMinutesParked() const;
        string getMake();
        string getModel();
        string getColor();
        string getLicense();
    
        // Mutators
        int setMinutesParked(int);
        void setMake(string ma);
        void setModel(string mo);
        void setColor(string c);
        void setLicense(string l);
    
    
    };
    
    #endif // PARKEDCAR_H
```

```
        ParkedCar.cpp


    #include "ParkedCar.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    
    
    ParkedCar::ParkedCar() // Default Constructor
    {
        minutesParked = 0;  
    }
    
    // make, model, color, licenseNumber;
    ParkedCar::ParkedCar(string ma, string mo, string c, string l, int mp) // Constructor with 5 parameters
    {
        carObject.setMake(ma);
        carObject.setModel(mo);
        carObject.setColor(c);
        carObject.setLicense(l);
        minutesParked = mp;
    }
    
    // Copy Constructor
    ParkedCar::ParkedCar(ParkedCar& obj)
    {
        carObject.setMake(obj.make);
        carObject.setModel(obj.model);
        carObject.setColor(obj.color);
        carObject.setLicense(obj.licenseNumber);
        minutesParked = obj.minutesParked;
    }
    
    // Accessors    
    string ParkedCar::getMake()
    {
        return make;
    }
    
    string ParkedCar::getModel()
    {
        return model;
    }
    
    string ParkedCar::getColor()
    {
        return color;
    }
    
    string ParkedCar::getLicense()
    {
        return licenseNumber;
    }
    
    int ParkedCar::getMinutesParked() const
    {
        return minutesParked;
    }
    
    // Mutators
    void ParkedCar::setMake(string ma)
    {
        make = ma;
    }
    
    void ParkedCar::setModel(string mo)
    {
        model = mo;
    }
    
    void ParkedCar::setColor(string c)
    {
        color = c;
    }
    
    void ParkedCar::setLicense(string l)
    {
        licenseNumber = l;
    }
    
    int ParkedCar::setMinutesParked(int mp)
    {
        minutesParked = mp;
        return 0;
    }
```

```
        ParkingMeter.h


    #pragma once
    #ifndef PARKINGMETER_H
    #define PARKINGMETER_H
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    
    
    class ParkingMeter
    {
    private:
        // Private Members
        int minutes; // Minutes purchased for parking
    
    public:
        // Constructors
        ParkingMeter();
        ParkingMeter(int);
    
        // Accessors
        int getMinutes();
    
        // Mutators
        int setMinutes(int);
    };
    
    #endif // PARKINGMETER_H
```

```
        ParkingMeter.cpp


    #include "ParkingMeter.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    
    // Default Constructor
    ParkingMeter::ParkingMeter()
    {
        minutes = 0;
    }
    
    // Constructor with 1 parameter
    ParkingMeter::ParkingMeter(int i)
    {
        minutes = i;
    }
    
    // Accessor
    int ParkingMeter::getMinutes()
    {
        return minutes;
    }
    
    // Mutator
    int ParkingMeter::setMinutes(int m)
    {
        minutes = m;
        return 0;
    }
    
    // Overload << operator
    const ostream& operator << (ostream& strm, const ParkingMeter& obj)
    {
        return strm;
    }
```

```
        PoliceOfficer.h


    #include "ParkingMeter.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    
    // Default Constructor
    ParkingMeter::ParkingMeter()
    {
        minutes = 0;
    }
    
    // Constructor with 1 parameter
    ParkingMeter::ParkingMeter(int i)
    {
        minutes = i;
    }
    
    // Accessor
    int ParkingMeter::getMinutes()
    {
        return minutes;
    }
    
    // Mutator
    int ParkingMeter::setMinutes(int m)
    {
        minutes = m;
        return 0;
    }
    
    // Overload << operator
    const ostream& operator << (ostream& strm, const ParkingMeter& obj)
    {
        return strm;
    }
```

```
        PoliceOfficer.cpp


    #include "PoliceOfficer.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    
    //Default Constructor
    PoliceOfficer::PoliceOfficer()
    {
        ParkingTicket* ticketPtr = nullptr;
        officerName = " ";
        badgeNumber = " ";
    }
    
    // Constructor with 2 elements
    PoliceOfficer::PoliceOfficer(string n, string b)
    {
        officerName = n;
        badgeNumber = b;
    }
    
    ParkingTicket *PoliceOfficer::patrol(ParkedCar car, ParkingMeter meter)
    {
        parkedMinutes = car.getMinutesParked();
        cout << "Parked Minutes: " << parkedMinutes << endl;
        meterMinutes = meter.getMinutes();
        cout << "Meter Minutes: " << meterMinutes << endl;
        minutes = parkedMinutes - meterMinutes;
        cout << "Minutes: " << minutes << endl;
        if (minutes <= 0)
        {
            return nullptr;
        }
        else
        {
            ParkingTicket ticket(car, minutes);
        };
        
    }
    // Accessors
    string PoliceOfficer::getOfficerName()
    {
        return officerName;
    }
    string PoliceOfficer::getBadgeNumber()
    {
        return badgeNumber;
    }
    
    // Mutators
    string PoliceOfficer::setOfficerName(string n)
    {
        officerName = n;
        return 0;
    }
    string PoliceOfficer::setBadgeNumber(string b)
    {
        badgeNumber = b;
        return 0;
    }
    
    // Overload << operator
    const ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const PoliceOfficer& obj)
    {   
        out << "Officer: " << &PoliceOfficer::getOfficerName;
        out << " (badge #" << &PoliceOfficer::getBadgeNumber;
        out << ")" << endl;
        return out;
    }
```

```
        ParkingTicket.h


    #pragma once
    #ifndef PARKINGTICKET_H
    #define PARKINGTICKET_H
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include "ParkedCar.h"
    #include "ParkingMeter.h"
    #include "Car.h"
    
    using namespace std;
    
    // ParkingTicket class simulates a parking ticket
    // Reports the car information for illegally parked car
    // Reports the fine which is $25 for the first hour or part
    // of an hour that the car is illegally parked, plus $10
    // for every additional hour or part of an hour
    
    class ParkingTicket
    {
    
    private:
        // Private Members
    //  class ParkedCar;
        double fine; // The calculated parking fine
        double* fineptr = &fine; // fine pointer
        int minutes; // The minutes illegally parked
        const int firstHour = 25; // first hour fine
        const int subHours = 10; // subsiquent hour fine
    
        // Car Info
        string make, model, color, licenseNumber;
    
    
    public:
        // Constructors
        ParkingTicket();
        ParkingTicket(ParkedCar car, int meter);
    
        // Accessors
        double getFine();
        int getMinutes();
    
        // Mutators
        double setFine(double);
        int setMinutes(int);
    
        // Method
        double fineCalc(); // calculate the fine
        string GetCarInfo();
    
    //  friend const ostream& operator << (ostream&, const ParkingTicket&);
    };
    
    const ostream& operator << (ostream&, const ParkingTicket&);
    
    #endif // PARKINGTICKET_H
```

```
        ParkingTicket.cpp


    #include "ParkingTicket.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;
    
    ParkingTicket::ParkingTicket() // Default Constructor
    {
        double fine = 0;
        double* fineptr = &fine;
        int minutes = 0;
        const int firstHour = 25;
        const int subHours = 10;
    }
    
    // Constructor with 2 parameters (ParkedCar and an integer)
    ParkingTicket::ParkingTicket(ParkedCar car, int min) 
    {
        minutes = min; // illegally parked minutes
        cout << "Minutes: " << endl;
        ParkingTicket::fineCalc(); // calculate fine
        cout << fine;
    }
    
    // Accessors
    double ParkingTicket::getFine()
    {
        return fine;
    }
    
    int ParkingTicket::getMinutes()
    {
        return minutes;
    }
    
    // Mutators
    double ParkingTicket::setFine(double f)
    {
        fine = f;
        return 0;
    }
    
    int ParkingTicket::setMinutes(int m)
    {
        minutes = m;
        return 0;
    }
    
    string GetCarInfo()
    {
        &Car::getMake;
        //&Car::getModel;
        //&Car::getColor;
        //&Car::getLicense;
    }
    
    // Car information, Time on the meter
    double ParkingTicket::fineCalc()
    {
        fine = 25;
        minutes -= 60;
        while (minutes >= 60)
        {
            fine += subHours;
            minutes -= 60;
        }
        if (minutes >= 0)
        {
            fine += subHours;       
        }
        return fine;
    }
    
    // Overload << operator
    const ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const ParkingTicket& obj)
    {
        out << &ParkingTicket::GetCarInfo;
        return out;
    }
```

```
        main.cpp


    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include "ParkedCar.h"
    #include "ParkingMeter.h"
    #include "ParkingTicket.h"
    #include "PoliceOfficer.h"
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
    
        ParkingTicket *ticket = nullptr;    
    
        ParkedCar car("Volkswagen", "1972", "Red", "147RHZM", 125);
    
        ParkingMeter meter(60);
    
        PoliceOfficer officer("Joe Friday", "4788");
    
        ticket = officer.patrol(car, meter);
        if (ticket != nullptr)
        {
            cout << "we made it this far officer" << endl;
            cout << officer;
            cout << "we are at the ticket" << endl;
            cout << *ticket;
    
            delete ticket;
            ticket = nullptr;
            
        }
        else
            cout << "No crimes were committed.\n";
    
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: you posted parkingmeter.cpp for policeofficer.h

Comment: That's way more code than you need for illustrating the problem. Please read about the [mcve].

Comment: Setters are not supposed to return anything, and returning `0` from a function returning `std::string` causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetCarInfo should return a string, but it doesn't:

```
string GetCarInfo()
{
    &Car::getMake;
}
```

hence the **error**.

`GetCarInfo` is a function in `ParkingTicket`, so you need to specify that as well in the definition. But I am not really sure what you intend to return here. You do not have a `Car` in context.

Maybe something like this?

```
string ParkingTicket::GetCarInfo()
{
    return make; //make is a private member of the class.
}
```

Anyway, the syntax `&Car::getMake;` is a *method function pointer*, pointing to a method in the class `Car`. Method function pointers are a bit exotic, so if you are new to programming, you probably did not mean to use that. If you meant to call the method `getMake` in `Car`, you should have an object of type `Car` to call on:

```
Car car;
car.getMake();
```

Note that the missing return statement in `PoliceOfficer::patrol` *only* emits a **warning** (in comparison with the error for the missing return in `GetCarInfo()`). It would be UB (Undefined Behavior) if you let the function end without returning (anything could happen!). So it's good that you are looking for the warning and want to fix them as well! The fix is to just add the return statement:

```
ParkingTicket PoliceOfficer::patrol(ParkedCar car, ParkingMeter meter)
{
    if (minutes <= 0)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        return ticket(car, minutes);
    };
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply miss a return statement here:

```
if (minutes <= 0)
        {
            return nullptr;
        }

 else
        {
            ParkingTicket ticket(car, minutes);
            // you must return something. I guess it is return ParkingTicket(...
        };
```

Same thing here:

```
string GetCarInfo()
    {
        &Car::getMake;
        //&Car::getModel;
        //&Car::getColor;
        //&Car::getLicense;
    }
```

You declare GetCarInfo() as a string you need to return a string.